# i need to write a query in oracle to check null value and display values

Tags: oracle

I want the query to perform this.

```
if parameter5 is not null then

select parameter1 from table where request_id = (select parameter5 from table)

if parameter is null then
select parameter1 from table
```

parameter5 contains the request id of the parent.If parameter5 is not null then i need the value of parameter1 of the parent request.if parameter5 is null then i need the value of parameter1.

### table

```
parameter1 | parameter5 | request_id
-----------|------------|------------
null       |  abc       | 123
123        |  bcd       | 234
null       |  xyz       | 456
```

say,the table looks like this.for request_id 234,the parameter5 value displayed should be 'abc'.for request_id 456,the parameter5 value displayed should be 'xyz'

How can i check the null condition and fetch the appropriate values.

Comment: Your explanation makes no sense. What you seem to be checking is if `parameter1` is null, not `parameter5`. Also `request_id = (select parameter5 from table)` (with no `where` conditions in the subquery) will produce errors, since the subquery on the right does not return a single value, it returns multiple values.

Comment: Do you just want to go up one level (when there is one level above), or do you actually need to go up the entire hierarchy, if it has more than one level? So what if, for example, `request_id = 234` has `parameter1 = 123`, and then `request_id = 123` has `parameter1 = 456`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well your need, you may need:

```
select t1.request_id, coalesce(t2.parameter5, t1.parameter5)
from yourTable t1
       left outer join yourTable t2 on ( t1.parameter1 = t2.request_id)
```

With your sample data, the result would be:

```
REQUEST_ID COA
---------- ---
       234 abc
       456 xyz
       123 abc
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to tell, since your description of the problem has several internal contradictions. (That's a fancy way to say "it makes no sense.") But, guessing from what you posted, perhaps this is what you need:

```
select request_id,
       case when parameter1 is null then parameter5
            else (select parameter5 from tbl where request_id = t.parameter1) 
        end as requested_value
from   tbl t
;
```

where `tbl` is the name of your table (which can't be `table` since that is a reserved word).

Answer (score 0):

```
with test_query as(
select 123 parameter1,'bcd' parameter5,234 request_id from dual
union all
select null , 'abc' , 123  from dual
union  all
select null, 'xyz',456 from dual
)
select  parameter5,nvl(prior request_id,request_id)
from test_query
where parameter1 is null
connect by  prior parameter1=request_id
```